# Java in CMD -- Trying to Compile and Run a Program

Tags: java, cmd

This photo album shows first, the location of the file on my computer, second, the source code, and third, the error message in CMD.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BpmP.jpg

Can anyone help me figure out why it is not compiling?

Comment: Please copy and paste the info here directly.

Answer (score 0):

Check your javac path on Windows  `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin` and copy the address.
and set your environment variables.
For step by step guide see [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Compile-%26-Run-Java-Program-Using-Command-Prompt)

or

```
C:\Directory goes here>set path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\bin;
C:\\Directory goes here>javac Hello.java
```